# Save data while system shutdown/restart/logout/logoff/application close for a WEB UI?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net, browser

I have a web application .let say in a page i have 2 label lbl1,lbl2 and correspopnding 2 txtbox.while the application open in web browser if i shutdown/restart/logout/logoff/close the application i want to save my data in a file(excel/xml).

Comment: You can try use browser's `onbeforeunload` event to catch the user leaving the page for any reason, but it is not always reliable

Comment: saving to `file` is a requirement? Else you can use other local storage options. What browsers do you target? What is the frequency of editing and amount of data? Is it viable to save the changes as data is edited?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.onbeforeunload` event.

Answer (score 0):

window.onbeforeunload event don't work if OS System is LogOff or Shutdown